# Get a list of persistent objects stored in database

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I should insert a list of objects in a database using a workflow for each object, the inserting process could take several time and waiting for some external input so I have to save persistent state in db, and it works correctly.

Now I need to show pending objects in my user interface, how can I retrieve variables of stored data??

Thank you,
Marco

Answer (score 1):

See [How to: Deserialize Instance Data Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960223.aspx)

Comment: Hello, I think this is how I can get primitive types, I read "This example does not demonstrate how to deserialize complex data properties because this is currently not a supported operation", am I wrong?

Comment: The data is there you just have to work out how to get it.  It is just serialized into dictionaries.