# How can i change data in InstancesTable

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm working with WF 4 and asp.net. I want to edit workflow (to back to previous step) and changing data in Instancetable but I don't know. My purpose is to undo to previous step without changing workflow designer and tables in sql updated automatic . my idea was change data in complex data properties in InstancesTable 
but I can't .I want a solution for editing previous activity without changeing workflow Designer and want to when back to previous step , Tables updated .
in the other hand , forexample , I want to back from activity 3 to activity 1 without any condition when activity3 don't executed.

Comment: I think you're looking to de-serialize the objects in the instances table, if so, this should point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530839/get-a-list-of-persistent-objects-stored-in-database

Answer (score 0):

you can use bookmark and return for specific bookmark 
if you just wanna return to the previous step 
I didn't try it 
but it should work the same if it forward or even backward